# upgrade from Google Local API V1.0.3 to Google Map API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can we upgrade from Google Local API V1.0.3 to Google Map API in our rails application.
Also what are the other better plugins to use like YM4R/GM.
Rails 2.3.4
Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: there are some tweaks to use gmaps4rails

Comment: yes, i'm looking around in the web, need to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using google_places gem [google_places](https://github.com/marceldegraaf/google_places), gem simply allows an easy interface to send the required HTTP requests and parse the JSON output into ruby hashes.

```
@client = GooglePlaces::Client.new("API_KEY")
@spot_list = @client.spots(-33.8670522, 151.1957362, :types => 'restaurant')
```

This hits https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json url.

Check [The Google Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/)  for other options which can be passed as search parameters.

parse through @spot_list and take out the reference of each place returned in response. Now, @client.spot "reference" will gives the details of the business.
In this case https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json is accessed to get the data